# how to require webpack bundles in js files

Tags: angularjs, webpack, bundle, router

I want to require two bundle files from webpack in an app.js that also gets bundled. My folder looks like this:

```
MyApp
|-app
|   -app.js  <-this gets bundled
|-hero
|  -hero.module  <- this gets also bundled
|  -some other stuff that will be bundled in hero.bundle.js
|-crisis
|  -crisis.module <- gets bundled
|  -more stuff that gets bundled in crisis.bundle.js
-
```

So far so good. 
I want to require hero.bundle.js and crisis.bundle.js in the app.js, because I am lazy loading / routing with my COmponent Router in app.js.
But I get constantly the Error, that the modules couldn't be found.
Example Syntax of one of the requires:

```
path: '/heroes/...',
            name: 'Heroes',
            loader: function () {
                // lazy load Heroes
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([require('./dist/heroes.bundle.js')])
                    .then(function () {
                        return 'heroes';
                    });
            }
```

Do I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you probably need this https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: I actually created the bundles in my webpack.config.js with entry and output, not the CommonsChunk.
the only thing is how I could include my bundle.js files into a javascript file, not an html

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:
Webpack didn't find my files. The path searched

C:/someFolders/heroApp/app/dist/heroes.bundle.js

altough it was

C:/someFolders/heroApp/dist/heroes.bundles.js

setting two dots was the solution:

```
require('../dist/heroes.bundle.js')
```